# Can a nontrivial function transform two non-independent random variables into two independent?

Tags: probability-theory

If two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, is it possible to find a nontrivial function $f$ so that $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ are independent? Thanks.

(I am trying to understand [if the simple uniform assumption for a hash function requires the keys to be independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4575891/how-shall-i-understand-the-uniform-hashing-assumption-of-a-hash-function).)

Comment: Nontrivial must mean non-constant here, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585379/independence-between-a-constant-random-variable-and-another-random-variable

Answer (score 1):

In some cases yes. Not a one-to-one function though, because if a (Borel measurable) left inverse function $g$ exists (i.e. $g(f(t)) = t$ for all possible values $t$ of $X$ and $Y$), then if $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ are independent, $X = g(f(X))$ and $Y = g(f(Y))$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also try to see if you can explain the assumption of simple uniform hashing in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4575891/how-shall-i-understand-the-uniform-hashing-assumption-of-a-hash-function